# Scaling a background image in android for a custom view (seekArc)

Tags: android, xml, background, android-custom-view, android-background

I have an image:

[image: Gauge]

This image is being set as the background for the seekArc (a circularized seekBar, found [here](https://github.com/TriggerTrap/SeekArc))

The problem is, when I set the image I have made to the background of the seekArc view; it extends past the actual arc of the seekArc; as seen with this [image: screenshot]

XML Code:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:seekarc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc
        android:id="@+id/SeekArc1"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/hometemp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/largepower"
        android:padding="85dp"
        seekarc:arcWidth="3dp"
        seekarc:max="100"
        seekarc:rotation="180"
        seekarc:startAngle="30"
        seekarc:sweepAngle="300"
        seekarc:touchInside="true" />

    <com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc
        android:id="@+id/SeekArc01"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/homepower"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/SeekArc1"
        android:padding="85dp"
        seekarc:arcWidth="3dp"
        seekarc:max="100"
        seekarc:rotation="180"
        seekarc:startAngle="30"
        seekarc:sweepAngle="300"
        seekarc:touchInside="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/hometemp"
        style="@style/tallerBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:maxHeight="50dp" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/homepower"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/SeekArc01"
        android:text="Power" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment code:

```
homeFragmentView = viewInflation.inflate(R.layout.homefragment_page,
                container, false);
        temp = (ProgressBar) homeFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.hometemp);
        power = (Switch) homeFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.homepower);
        s1 = (SeekArc) homeFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.SeekArc1);
        s2 = (SeekArc) homeFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.SeekArc01);

        Resources res = homeFragmentView.getResources();
        Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.largepower);
        if (drawable.equals(null)) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "NOT NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        s1.setBackground(drawable);
        }
```

What would be a good method about getting the seekArc to go around the image?

Comment: whete do you keep the image ?

Comment: In my drawable folder

Comment: try for testing move it to drawable-nodpi

Comment: I do not have a drawable-nodpi folder. Just the regular drawable and then drawable- with various DPI.

Comment: yes, try to create xml bitmap file http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap with gravity = center and use it instead of "@
drawable/largepower"

Comment: I attempted that and it yielded the same results; refer to my edit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49971/discussion-between-tukajo-and-pskink)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating a custom bitmap.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/small"
    android:antialias="false"
    android:dither="false"
    android:filter="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:mipMap="false"
    android:tileMode="disabled" />
```

and placing it within a new folder @drawable-nodpi that I created in my res.

Then I referred to a manually-scaled image of the size I needed.